# Php string inside alt inside php echo

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Im using Wordpress + WPML to translate. I need to insert a string (to be able of translating later) inside of a ALT that is inside of a php echo... I have tried using '' to separate html from php but seems that I'm missing something.

Putting this code inside the alt:

Gives an error.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '''' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'
```

This is the code:

```
 // START Condition Icon 1 
 $ico1 = get_post_meta($post->ID,'wpcf-ico-diving', true); 
 if ( $ico1) 
 {
    echo '<li alt="'<?php
    _e('Scuba Diving Tulum', 'aguaclaraproject');?>'" class="i1 icommon"></li>';
 }
 else {
   // Show Nothing 
 } // END
```

I appreciate your help to allow me understand better how php works and solve this issue.

Answer (score 4):

You're already inside the php script, remove the php tags and concatenate it properly.

```
echo '<li alt="'. _e('Scuba Diving Tulum', 'aguaclaraproject') . '" class="i1 icommon"></li>';
```

Or like this:

```
$alt = _e('Scuba Diving Tulum', 'aguaclaraproject');
echo "<li alt='$alt' class='i1 icommon'></li>";
```

Or lastly:

```
$alt = __('Scuba Diving Tulum', 'aguaclaraproject');
echo "<li alt='$alt' class='i1 icommon'></li>";
```

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '_e' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'...` why I get this error when I try to do this:

Comment: @glowzar did you try both answers? on this end, should be working fine

Comment: I get error with both of the solutions suggested.... for example, none works. both gives me php error, the error: ` Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '_e' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in /homepages/46/d448593520/htdocs/wp-content/themes/aguaclaraproject/single-diveshop.php on line 25` My code: `.// START Condition Icon 1
$ico1 = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-ico-diving', true);
if ( $ico1) {
 echo '<li class="i1 icommontooltip" title=".'_e('Scuba Diving', 'aguaclaraproject')'."></li>';
}
else {
// Show Nothing
}
// END`

Comment: @glowzar i haven't used wordpress before but it seems when `_e()` is invoked, it already carries the `echo`, try to use `__()` so that it returns a string and can be concatenated by other strings

Comment: @glowzar `echo '<li class="i1 icommontooltip" title="'._e('Scuba Diving', 'aguaclaraproject').'"></li>';`

Comment: @glowzar or use `echo '<li class="i1 icommontooltip" title="'.__('Scuba Diving', 'aguaclaraproject').'"></li>';`

Comment: this one did the job:) thanks man!!! i will read in depth now to see what i was doing wrong. `echo '<li class="i1 icommontooltip" title="'.__('Scuba Diving', 'aguaclaraproject').'"></li>';`

Comment: @glowzar yes that was my assumption too, `_e` already has an echo inside thats why it causes some errors, anyway im glad this helped